# Javascript Dispatch Event Within Iframe

Tags: javascript

I am opening a site in an iframe, There is a `div` in which I want to click its element with the ID `#thearea`.

When I "target" `#thearea`, do the co-ordinates that I have set are relative to `#thearea`, or are they relative to the window / document as a whole?

So basically with the example below having `10,10` as x/y co-ordinates is that `10/10` from the corner of the window or `10/10` from the corner of the `div` called `#thearea` which is being targeted.

```
v = frames[1];


target = v.document.getElementById('thearea');


    var oEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
oEvent.initMouseEvent(
   'click'          // event type
   ,true           // can bubble?
   ,true          // cancelable?
   ,window      // the event's abstract view (should always be window)
   ,0              // mouse click count (or event "detail")
   ,0        // event's screen x coordinate
   ,0          // event's screen y coordinate
   ,10           // event's client x coordinate
   ,10           // event's client y coordinate
   ,false         // whether or not CTRL was pressed during event
   ,false         // whether or not ALT was pressed during event
   ,false         // whether or not SHIFT was pressed during event
   ,false         // whether or not the meta key was pressed during event
   ,1             // indicates which button (if any) caused the mouse event (1 = primary button)
   ,null          // relatedTarget (only applicable for mouseover/mouseout events)
);


    target.dispatchEvent( oEvent );
```